# How to get all CSS and Javascript files by chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension which can get all the CSS and Javascript files' names and content in a web page by clicking a button in Page Action, but I don't know which API can do this work.

Answer (score 1):

In the Chrome DevTools API there exists a method `inspectedWindow.getResources` which returns a list of scripts and stylesheets and provides methods for getting their content. However, its only available when the page is being inspected.

An alternative would be to use a content-script, and communicate the desired info back to your popup via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

To get the CSS and JS file info from within the content-script:

```
var js = document.scripts;
var css = document.styleSheets;
```

To get the file content, you can make an ajax request from the content-script, using the file URL's.

Comment: the way you give me to get the js and css is awesome!
but when I use ajax to get the file content, it will send a http request again. Actually, these content was already in the broswer. Is there any method to get them?

Comment: And another problem is -- it doesn't include those images, fonts and css files which were imported in the css files

Comment: @XiuXiu. I don't believe you can get the content without another http request. In the DevTools API there exists a method `inspectedWindow.getResources` which does what you want, however it is not available from a popup, and only works when the dev-tools is open.

Comment: A JS or CSS file is just plain text. Parsing image or font imports is your responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, what a pity that it only works when the devTool is open. So I think I have to analyse all css files' content, and fetch the images and fronts in them...

Comment: @XiuXiu. Its possible the chrome will cache the files, in which case the http request will be instantaneous.